# Logarithm Via Multiplication By Some Function

Tags: functions, logarithms

This question may be totally rubbish, I'm not sure...

Basically, I'm wondering if I have some expression, say,
$$f(z)A(z)$$
where $A(z)$ is some arbitraryly changing function in $z$ totally out of my control, is there are function, $f(z)$, by which I can multiply $A(z)$, which results in me taking the logarithm of $A(z)$?

I have a feeling the answer is simply no...  and this is a really silly question, but just wanting to make sure.

Thanks.

Comment: This may be obvious, but if $A$ is bijective then yes.

Comment: Okay, so I'm an engineering student, so had to look up bijective.  $A(z)$ isn't bijective.

Comment: Well, not to be too sarcastic, but doesn't $$f(z) = \frac{\ln(A(z))}{A(z)}$$ work? I am assuming $A(z)$ is nonzero and positive, since we can take its logarithm.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't k now how to write it properly.  $A(z)$ is unknown to me, so I can't choose an $f(z)$ in terms of $A(z)$ because I don't know what $A(z)$ will be.  I'd need to find an $f(z)$ that works for any $A(z)$ I guess.

Comment: For some reason my brain thought $A^{-1}(z) = \frac{1}{A(z)}$; please disregard my last comment.

Comment: I think that $\dfrac{\ln A(z)}{A(z)}$ is the _only_ function that would work. So, if you want a function that doesn't depend on $A$, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining $f(z) = {Log(A(z)) \over A(z)}$ for $A(z) \in \mathbb{R}^+$ (not positive $A(z)$ does not makes sense, since you want $log(A(z))$ to exist.

EDIT:
Since author requires $f(z)$ to work for any $A(z)$, the answer is simply no. There is no constant $c$ such that $c\cdot A(z)= log(A(z))$ for general $A(z)$